# How to get system locale in Windows 7 cmd?

Tags: windows, localization, utf-8

How can I get system locale in Windows 7?

I mean something like: cs_CZ.UTF-8

I tried writing "locale" in the command line but that doesn't work in Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's not a specific command (or at least, not one that I'm aware of) to get this information, but you can find it between those provided by `systeminfo.exe`.

Comment: When running systeminfo on a command line, a lot of information is output to the screen. The relevant information to look for is:
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)

Comment: systeminfo /FO csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select *locale

Comment: @Ogrish Man : This seems to be a Powershell command, but it gives me no output. Maybe because the headers are not in English. `systeminfo.exe` by itself works, as does gWaldo's answer in PS

Answer (score 12):

`Get-UICulture` or `Get-Host` in PowerShell

(capitalization optional)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your proposals fail, because they rely on searching a string ("*System Locale*") which changes depending on the current locale!
On my french Win10Pro, the string is "*Option régionale du système*" (with accented letter, which is very difficult to handle properly in a CMD file).

I've done some testing, and it seems, on MY system, that the lines about locale in systeminfo output are the only ones to contain a semi-colon character (";"):

```
24/09/2017 17:18:43,23 | C:\CMD ()
> systeminfo | findstr ;
Option régionale du système:                fr;Français (France)
Paramètres régionaux d'entrée:              fr;Français (France)
```

Based on that (which may NOT be true on other systems with different languages), I coded this **get_locale.cmd** script :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion    
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN ('systeminfo.exe ^|  findstr ";"') do  (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2-3 delims=:;" %%B in (`echo %%A`) do (
        set VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE=%%C
        REM Removing useless leading spaces ...
        FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %%D in (`echo %%B`) do (
            set SYSTEM_LOCALE=%%D
        )
        set SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON=!SYSTEM_LOCALE!;
    set | findstr /I locale
    REM No need to handle second line, quit after first one
    goto :EOF
    )
)
```

The result of my script on MY system is:

```
24/09/2017 17:18:45,31 | C:\CMD ()
> get_locale.cmd
SYSTEM_LOCALE=fr
SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON=fr;
VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE=Français (France)
```

Be warned, however, that the three environment variables exist only inside the script, they do NOT persist in CMD environment after the script ends (no *export* command as in *nix).

Answer (score 1):

me again.

I discovered a slight enhancement to my script. Using SETX one can store environment variables into USER environment for **future** CMD Windows to use (as stated in **SETX /?** second remark).

Then the **get_locale.cmd** script becomes:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion    
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN ('systeminfo.exe ^|  findstr ";"') DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2-3 delims=:;" %%B IN (`echo %%A`) DO (
        SET VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE=%%C
        setx VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE "%%C" 1>NUL
        REM Removing useless leading spaces ...
        FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %%D IN (`echo %%B`) DO (
            SET SYSTEM_LOCALE=%%D
            setx SYSTEM_LOCALE %%D 1>NUL
        )
        SET SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON=!SYSTEM_LOCALE!;
        setx SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON !SYSTEM_LOCALE!; 1>NUL
    SET | findstr /I locale
    REM No need to handle second line, quit after first one
    GOTO :EOF
    )
)
```

For the VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE variable, since the value is possibly several words long, it is required to wrap %%C into quotes so that SETX receives only one parameter as expected.

Now, in any **new** CMD window, these values will be available:

```
16/12/2017  2:00:46 | C:\Users\Seagram ()
>set | findstr /i locale
SYSTEM_LOCALE=fr
SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON=fr;
VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE=Français (France)
```

*PS: It would be nice if other contributors from other countries with other languages could confirm that looking for semi-colon ';' works on their Windows systems. Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Please consider combining this answer with your previous one.

Comment: @Seagram - thanks for this - I can confirm that it workds for English (United Kingom): `System Locale:             en-gb;English (United Kingdom)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the actual locale to conditionally do other things in a batch file you can create a batch file (save a text file as .bat extension) with the following. As a starting point this will print to the command prompt, for example, "en-us" (no quotes) You can also use the variable !VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE! for the human readable locale e.g. English(UnitedStates)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims==" %%G IN ('systeminfo.exe') Do  (
    set input=%%G
    for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do if "!input:~-1!"==" " set input=!input:~0,-1!
    IF "!input:~0,13!"=="System Locale" (
        set answer=!input:~15!
        set answer=!answer: =!
        set VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE=!answer:*;=!
        call set SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON=%%answer:!VERBOSE_SYSTEM_LOCALE!=%%
        set SYSTEM_LOCALE=!SYSTEM_LOCALE_WITH_SEMICOLON:~0,-1!
        echo !SYSTEM_LOCALE!        
   )
)
```